# What does 'paint-peeling' mean here?

Tags: word-meaning

The following is from The Golden Spruce by John Vaillant

> When all was ready, the bull whacker, using that astonishing
>   combination of tender endearment and **paint-peeling** invective
>   unique to drivers of animals and machines, would cajole his team into
>   motion.

What does '**paint-peeling**' mean here? rough, harsh?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Compare

> She had a singing voice that could peel paint.

She sang very poorly indeed. Her voice was harsh, like a chemical used to remove paint, or like a scraping blade against the paint.

> She used expletives like there was no tomorrow. She had a mouth on her that could peel paint.

There's an implicit analogy:

harsh paint remover : paint ::   {x}  : { sensibilities}

Comment: What does "paint :: {x} : { sensibilities} " mean? Is it some kind of code?

Comment: @whitecap: `a : b :: c : d` is spoken "a is to b as c is to d". It is a way of representing an analogy. http://english.tutorvista.com/vocabulary/analogies.html